# Getting a subgroup into an array with Regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the items under a sentence into an array but having trouble.

```
"this is a sentence"
-foo
-bar
-bat
"this is another sentence"
-akn
-yui
-bui
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
/(^\"[\s\S]*?\")\n*((?:-.*\n*)*)/gm
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/vD4zI8/1)

The match comes back as a string like:

```
[0] = '-foo
-bar
-bat
'
```

but I need it as:

```
[0] = `"this is a sentence"`
[1] = `-foo`
[2] = `-bar`
[3] = `-bat`
...
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but new to regexp. Take in mind that in my application, I'm trying to:  ***find a sentence with or without items under it*** and return an array of the results

Comment: I did. please click on the link

Comment: iterate over each item in the list and then do splitting according to the newline character.

Comment: Ive seen it done with regexp but cant remember the formula

Comment: Whatever you can't do in one step, do in two.

Comment: @Coldstar: Please include the test cases and the regex in the question next time. Don't put it exclusively on external site, just in case it goes down.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to match everything in one attempt, match each line on a different attempt.

```js
var regex = /^(\"[^"]*\"|-.*)/gm; 
var pre = document.getElementById('text');
var str = pre.innerHTML;
 
var result = str.match(regex);

pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<pre id="text">
"this is a sentence"
-foo
-bar
-bat
"this is another sentence"
-akn
-yui
-bui
</pre>
```

Comment: JUST about to post my answer and click back in here and you have answered with identical RegEx. +1

Comment: I sware I'm not playing *fastest gun in the west*!